# Program crashes when attempting to print a character

Tags: c

I copied this exercise from my book.

Use this declaration char *string = "hiii";
what are value for

```
1) string[0]
2) *string
3) string[99]
4) *string+8
```

I wrote the following code in an attempt to display the value of `string[0]`, but when I run the code, it crashes.  Can anyone tell me why my code crashes?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *string = "hiii";
    printf("%s", string[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error/warning messages do you get when compiling? If you do not get *any* errors or warnings, consult your compiler documentation on how to increase the level of warnings and errors reporting.

Comment: Additionally, since you *copied* this out of a text book: 1. Are you sure you copied it correctly? 2. If you did, find another text book. This error is "bad" and should not have been made in a text book.

Comment: No the book is asking what is the value for string[0].. etc. I wrote the code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
printf("%s", string[0]);
```

`s` conversion specifier requires a `char *` but `string[0]` is a `char`.

Use:

```
printf("%s", string);
```

to print the string.

To print the first character of the string, use:

```
printf("%c", string[0]);
```

Comment: Better to close this question, not answer it.

Comment: @djechlin did you downvote the answer? Is there something wrong with this answer?

Comment: Yes, this answer is not useful. It encourages bad questions which leads to answerers abandoning the site as a hobby entirely. So don't answer bad questions.

Comment: @user3579248 you will be question banned if your questions continue to receive largely downvotes and are closed.

Comment: @djechlin It is not useful for you but it is useful for beginners and students! Stop be arrogant, stop down-vote every question/answer!

Comment: @djechlin If you think the question is bad, you should downvote the question not the correct answers. And as far as I am concerned, I answer the questions I want.

Comment: I did downvote the question. The tooltip above the downvote says "This answer is not useful." That statement is true, so I downvoted. @user3579248 it's not useful for future visitors. It's not useful for other beginners in particular, because if they knew how to put enough research to find this question, they would find dozens of other resources, including SO questions, first.

Comment: Finally found it, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252531/1339987 and pretty much all of meta.SO lately.

Answer (score -1):

Program crashes, because place, where it expects pointer eg. *char , as it was written above by ouah is filled by value of some character. However if we consider it as pointer, it shows to place with no sense. So your program crashes.